# Selecting unique years from timestamp - results not as expected

Tags: php, mysql

Trying to select unique years from timestamp column in a table but so far unsuccesful. There are about 50 rows with 3 unique years between them.

```
$getyears = $dbh->prepare("SELECT DISTINCT DATE_FORMAT(timestamp, '%Y') as timestamp FROM press");
$getyears->execute();
$years = $getyears->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

print_r($years);
```

The result of this is:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [timestamp] => ) )
```

There should be three different years.

I'm no expert in MySQL and quite new to PDO. Can't see where I'm going wrong.

**Updated**

I enclosed `timestamp` with back ticks but still the same result.

Printing the error info `print_r($getyears->errorInfo());` returned:

```
Array ( [0] => 00000 [1] => [2] => )
```

`timestamp` is a `int` type field and after a double check, the table as a whole definitely contains 3 unique years.

**Updated 2**

Just a bit more info:

All rows have either of the following in the `timestamp` field (`int(11)`):

```
1230587568
1262123568
1356817968
```

Comment: how about `SELECT DISTINCT YEAR(timestamp) as ts ..`

Comment: Enclose the timestamp column name in backticks - timestamp is a MySQL reserved word, which could be causing problems

Comment: Done that, same issue I'm afraid.

Comment: There is no problem with query nor with php code. it must be data then

Comment: @dev-null-dweller what kind of checks would you suggest I do?

Comment: I was about suggesting that you are connecting to wrong database, that has only null values in timestamp column. But then you edited and provided info that you are using `int` and not `timestamp` datatype, so it's kinda problem with the data ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can show the error with

```
print_r($dbh->errorInfo());
```

or

```
print_r($getyears->errorInfo());
```

According to [Reserved Words](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html), it is allowed to use `timestamp` unquoted. Although, it is a good habit to quote it with backticks anyway.

[`date_format`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) works with a `date` type and not with an `int` type. If `timestamp` is a unix timestamp (seconds since 1970-01-01), you can try [`from_unixtime`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_from-unixtime) instead.